# Given a first fundamental form, showing a particular second form cannot exist

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

If I have a first fundamental form $
\mathrm{d}u^2+\cos^2 u \mathrm{d}v^2$, I am trying to show that the second fundamental form cannot equal $f(u,v)\mathrm{d}v^2$ for a smooth function $f(u,v)$.

I have calculated the Christoffel symbols and arrived at the following set of equations:

$\sigma_{uu} = L \cdot \mathbf{N}$

$\sigma_{uv} = -\tan u \cdot \sigma_v + M \cdot \mathbf{N}$

$\sigma_{vv} = \tan u \cdot \sigma_u + N \cdot \mathbf{N}$

I suppose I was expecting to arrive at a contradiction, but I can't really see where any problem occurs with the fundamental form only having a coefficient for $N$

I know that both fundamental forms of a sphere are $\mathrm{d} u^2+ \cos^2 u \mathrm{d}v^2$ but does having such a first fundamental form necessarily imply that the surface is a sphere?

Comment: Hint: The Gauss-curvature can be computed from the second fundamental form, but it depends only on the first fundamental form.

Comment: Given $E=1, F=0, G=\cos ^2 u$, $K = \frac{LN-M^2}{EG-F^2}$ and $K=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{G}} \mathrm{d}^2 \frac{(\sqrt G)}{\mathrm{d}u^2}$

Comment: So $K = 1$ from the second formula, so by the first formula, we require $LN-M^2=EG-F^2$ which is impossible if $L=0$. Is this correct?

Comment: I am not sure about the formulae you suggest, but the Gauss curvature is just the determinant of the second fundamental form, and the second fundamental form you want to achieve evidently is degenerate and hence has determinant zero. On the other hand, as you noted, the surface is isometric to a sphere and hence has non-zero Gauss curvature.